# MPI communication between processors of different nodes

Tags: c, mpi

I am new to MPI and bit confused about the data communication between CPUs of different nodes. How do cpus communicate data between them when they are located in different nodes?

For example I want to send and recv data from once to other :

```
MPI_Send(
    void* data, // This is a pointer that cpu-1 in Node-1 want to sent to cpu-2 in node-2,
    int count,
    MPI_Datatype datatype,
    int destination,
    int tag,
    MPI_Comm communicator)

MPI_Recv(
    void* data, // I receive the pointer from Node-1, but this pointer corresponds to different memory in Node-2. How does this work?
    int count,
    MPI_Datatype datatype,
    int source,
    int tag,
    MPI_Comm communicator,
    MPI_Status* status)
```

Comment: This is implementation specific. Long story short, MPI detects the available networks (such as TCP/IP or Infiniband) and chooses the best fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MPI was written in the early 1990s when the concept of a core didn't exist. So processes were *always* on a different node. The first implementation on the MPI routines probably used Unix sockets to send data over ethernet cables. Current implementations use whatever networking library the system provides, which can go over Infiniband or Ethernet or whatever is there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, If I understood correctly, there is always a data transfer( i.e data replication on the received node) and the recv function returns pointer to that replicated memory?

Comment: Yes, an ordinary send/recv operation always involves data transfer, over a wire if the cores are on different nodes, or by copying if the cores are on the same node. Because of the process model, there is never shared data (unless you get into very advanced stuff): you can indeed consider the send operation as a replication, at least in simple cases.

Comment: the recv function does **not** "return a pointer". It is up to the user to pass a valid pointer, and MPI will "populate" the buffer accordingly with the content of the received message.